# Webdriver parallel execution using test data from spreadsheet

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using spreadsheet (MS Excel) to provide test data for my test suite.

I tried to execute my selenium webdriver test suite in parallel grid. But, out of 5 parallel instances, only one gets the test data from spreadsheet.

I don't understand the possible cause that would led to such behaviour.

Please help me.

Comment: Please provide more information, e.g. the smallest amount of code you can find that reproduces the problem.  It is impossible to diagnose issues like this without code.

Answer (score 0):

Possible cause can be;

- Use of static methods to read the excel.
- Use of same instance of excel reader class in test classes.

Please provide more information.